# ALS with binary input

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

I have a Collaborative system built with Spark ALS. Instead of rating, I wanted to recommend set products to the user based on what they have purchased. So I have set 1 for all the products purchased by the user. and built an ALS system. The prediction has more than 1 as score and also rmse is 0.99. I have set implicitprefs =True. Please find the code below. Is not it too high to have rmse as 0.99. Is it a right approach?

Note: I have improved iteration and rank parameter with for loop.

```
Ratings = Ratings.withColumn("Ordered",Ratings["Ordered"].cast('int'))
    Ratings = Ratings.withColumn("UserId", Ratings["UserId"].cast('int'))
    Ratings = Ratings.withColumn("ProductId", Ratings["ProductId"].cast('int'))
    Ratings = Ratings.na.drop()
(train, test) = Ratings.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
Model = (ALS(maxIter=3,regParam=0.01,rank=4,
userCol="UserId",itemCol="ProductId",ratingCol="Ordered",
implicitPrefs=True,nonnegative=True))
    Fit = Model.fit(train)
    print(Model.getImplicitPrefs)
    Pred = Fit.transform(test)
    Pred = Pred.na.drop()
    Pred.toPandas().to_csv("Prediction.csv")
    print("before printing")
    #print(Pred.show(100))
    Evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse",labelCol="Ordered",predictionCol="prediction")
    rmse = Evaluator.evaluate(Pred)
    print("rmse is",str(rmse))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is an Implicit Feedback problem, so set `implicitprefs = True` is necessary. According to Spark documentation, they are using the this paper for the implementation. 
http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf
The paper also mentioned mean-squared-error is not appropriate. ROC related metrics are better. All the binary classification metrics are suitable. 
Another thought is that instead of using binary coding feedback, you can still use the number of items purchased or dollars spent on that item as the input, since you are using `implicitprefs = True`.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about your approach. If your data set has only binary feedback, the metric you use is not appropriate. The RMSE is used for regressions (i. e. the prediction of continuous values). For recommendation systems that work with implicit feedback, a suitable metric would be precision or recall. Cremonsesi et al. wrote a great paper on evaluating Top-N Recommender Systems (https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2507225).